# Selective vertical whitespace in matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm trying to create some extra vertical whitespace in a legend produced using `matplotlib.pyplot`.  However, want this extra whitespace to only be between two entries in the legend, while the remaining entries are left untouched.  I have a MWE and the image it produces, edited to show where I want the extra whitespace.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0,1],[.2,.2],label = "A")
plt.plot([0,1],[.4,.4],label = "B")
plt.plot([0,1],[.6,.6],label = "C")
plt.plot([0,1],[.8,.8],label = "D")

plt.legend(loc='upper right',labelspacing=.3)
plt.ylim(0,1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably have to use a Proxy Artist for this. Here is an example:

```
a, = plt.plot([0,1],[.2,.2],label = "A")
b, = plt.plot([0,1],[.4,.4],label = "B")
c, = plt.plot([0,1],[.6,.6],label = "C")
d, = plt.plot([0,1],[.8,.8],label = "D")

plt.legend([a,b,c,matplotlib.lines.Line2D([],[],linestyle=''),d],['A','B','C','','D'], loc='upper right',labelspacing=.3)
plt.ylim(0,1)
```

[image]

Comment: When I use your code, I get a box around my legend (which is fine, I want the box).  How come your image doesn't have a box around the legend despite being the same code?

Comment: Probably a difference on our matplotlibrc file http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\n` in labels.

Note, that the label is centered to the marker, so use 2 `\n`.

```
plt.plot([0,1],[.6,.6],label = "\nC\n")
```